# USB storage emulator

Tags: automated-testing, dot-net

I need to emulate insertion and removal of SD cards to write tests. What is the best way/tool to implement it in .NET?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can write one on Windows with [DSF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff538293%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), but I don't think there's a sample for SD cards at this time.

Comment: +1 As usual, Alan, your "insider" knowledge is indispensable.

Comment: I do my best. As an aside, I wrote a chapter about DSF for Dorothy Graham's upcoming book on automation case studies. Hopefully out sometime this fall...or winter...

Answer (score 1):

Sadly I don't know how to do this myself, but I found this:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/usbeject.aspx

Could be a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the devcon command line utility to disable/enable the SD card, not very elegant but will be the fastest way.
[support.microsoft.com/kb/311272](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311272)